# .Click in a Onchange not working on Mac OS but works on Windows/linux

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

so I have an HTML part which is like

```
<select name="espece-prise" id="espece-prise" size="1" onchange="selectespece();">
    <option value="{liste.espece}">{liste.espece}</option>
</select>
```

then I have an `input type='file'` in order to upload an image, this input is hidden and has the class 'btn_poster_photo'.

**What I want**

when the user uses the select (and click on an option) it triggers the 'onchange' and through the 'selectespece()' function a click on the hidden button thanks to the .Click function in selectespece().So after all these js function the result is:

select an option => it opens a window where you choose the file to upload

**What I did**

```
function selectespece() {
    especeprise = $("#espece-prise").val();  //just a variable getting the value of my select (it works)
    document.getElementById("btn_poster_photo").click();
}
```

I also did it in many different ways with jQuery

```
$("#espece-prise").on('change', function(){
    especeprise = $("#espece-prise").val();
    $(".btn_poster_photo").click();
})
```

**What is happening?**

When I select an option it triggers the click so it asks me to upload an image which is alright. This works on Chrome/Firefox/Opera... when I do it from a Windows/Ubuntu/archlinux computer

**BUT**

When I try it on safari/chrome from a MacOS it doesn't work, no error in console, I just select something and nothing happens. I tried to put an alert in my function 'onchange' it works, all works but not the .Click function...

I made several searches on Google but only found a few topics talking about an onclick after an onchange but not a .click in an onchange.

Comment: Did you try $(".btn_poster_photo").trigger("click"); ?

Comment: isn't trigger a "one-shot" function ? i mean if i select somthing then close the file windows and select another one it will trigger again ?

Comment: It will be triggered every time when your selectespece() function is called. You call selectespece() which triggers click. It would be one-shot on window load or document ready.

Comment: ok i tried to change the .Click by a trigger('click') and it doesn't work either :/

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkjrb5np/3/) - it is working ok for me on both OS. Are you using Angular? Why dont you use ng-change attribute? Or it is just template insert into html?

Comment: I'm not using angular so i cant use the ng-change attribute i guess...                     that's a select i create with data from my database

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zkjrb5np/4/ is this one working for you ?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, I tried with select everything and it is not working, but a solution with button positioned underneath opacity: 0 input file - works all the time. Some people suggest to call .blur() event with select instead of change - but I am not sure i will trigger anything...

Comment: finally i changed the system and add a button, i have no idea why a .click in the onchange doesn't work for some devices but that's the case....

Answer (score 0):

You can only programmatically trigger a file dialog window from a user-initiated event.

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/programmatically-opening-a-file-dialog-with-javascript

In this case, I'm not sure if a `change` event would count, as typically a user-initiated event would be something like `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `scroll`, `resize`, `keyup`, etc.

Perhaps try to refactor to react to one of the above events (from your `<select>`) instead.

Comment: i tried with a onclick event on the select that works approximatly as the onchange but it doesn't work :/